# Android Tutorials Not Mentioning Fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments

I'm trying to follow android tutorials and I seem to keep running into the same problem: **Most tutorials mention nothing about fragments**, and my up-to-date version of the android SDK automatically creates a fragment_main.xml in the layout folder.

[My Issue Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/unqgY.jpg)

Tutorials such as this one (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/getting-started#login) require me to follow step by step, and my apps end up not working because there are major differences in my .java file right off the bat.

In this specific example, I followed the facebook sdk tutorial linked above step by step, and in the end I had a ton of errors trying to include their steps in my differing code such as:

```
"The method onCreate(Bundle) of type MainActivity must override or implement a supertype method"
```

and

```
"The method setContentView(int) is undefined for the type MainActivity".
```

In the tutorial at the end, it provides the full MainActivity.java file. At that point, I replaced my code with their code, and the errors went away, but the app actually fails right at the start, saying "Unfortunately, FacebookLoginApp has stopped".

**Is there any way to stay up-to-date with current practices while still being able to use tutorials like this?**

If I need to provide any more information, please just let me know.

Thanks in advance, I really appreciate the help I receive on this website.

If this helps, **here is my entire MainActivity.java file that I created** going through the tutorial, NOT the one that I copied in afterward.

```
package com.facebookloginapp;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.os.Build;
import com.facebook.*;
import com.facebook.model.*;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.content.Intent;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment()).commit();
    }

      // start Facebook Login
      Session.openActiveSession(this, true, new Session.StatusCallback() {

        // callback when session changes state
        @Override
        public void call(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {

            if (session.isOpened()) {
                // make request to the /me API
                Request.newMeRequest(session, new Request.GraphUserCallback() {

                  // callback after Graph API response with user object
                  @Override
                  public void onCompleted(GraphUser user, Response response) {
                      if (user != null) {
                          TextView welcome = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.welcome);
                          welcome.setText("Hello " + user.getName() + "!");
                        }
                  }
                }).executeAsync();
                }

        }
      });

}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
  super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
  Session.getActiveSession().onActivityResult(this, requestCode, resultCode, data);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

/**
 * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
 */
public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

    public PlaceholderFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container,
                false);
        return rootView;
    }
}

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to use fragments.  For many, many apps fragments aren't necessary and make your app less readable.  I'd go so far as to say most apps do not use them.  Just because they're new things doesn't mean you should use them.  Decide based on what your app is trying to do if it makes sense or not.  In the meantime it makes 0 sense to change existing tutorials to use fragments unless doing so will make them clearer-  which is going to be a very small percentage of tutorials, since tutorials tend to be written very simply with a minimal of fancy UI.

Comment: That is the most comforting thing I've heard this week. Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 2):

While creating a new Application, just copy the Layout Name to the Fragment Layout Name (e.g. activity_main)

You get an activity without the fragment part.
[image]

remove this part of the code from activity

```
if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment())
                .commit();
```

Clean your project.

Answer (score 1):

**Is there any way to stay up-to-date with current practices while still being able to use tutorials like this?**

Yes. You have to adapt the tutorial yourself as you go. For your example, learn about fragments well enough to translate FB's old crusty tutorial code into the modern parlance to the point that it runs. This may involve multiple SO posts. But you will learn it thoroughly.

It's like having exercises built in!

Yes, it's hard. Programming is hard. And fragments are freakin' wack. But dig through the documentation and you'll find there are enough parallels to cobble together a working implementation.